# What should i use for rails file attachment and jruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, jruby, attachment, carrierwave

Normally I'd use carrierwave, but they do not officially support jruby, and I've been running in to bugs, possibly related. (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/620, [Image corruption on upload to s3, production only.  (carrierwave, engineyard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236143/image-corruption-on-upload-to-s3-production-only-carrierwave-engineyard))

Have others had success here?

I'm considering trying out paperclip, but it looks like that may not be perfect either-- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/100

Comment: Apparently the bug that affected your uploading (which also affected dragonfly) has been fixed in Jruby. Carrierwave works with jruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) it's a really great library to manage you file attachment.

Comment: I don't use jruby, but this library is test on Jruby too.

Answer (score 0):

check out this guide, it's cake
http://webtempest.com/how-to-allow-image-uploads-in-rails-on-heroku/

It uses paperclip and amazon web s3 gems

Comment: have you used paperclip with jruby?

Comment: no i haven't sorry.  I didn't even read that in your question :(